# How can I access this property based on this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

Example, lets say I have the following Constructor function defined in window global of a browser.

```
function AccessProperty() {
  this.myName = "Chris";
}
```

Now I execute this function like this:

```
new AccessProperty();
```

Now based on how I executed the function above with the new keyword, how can I access `this.myName` property without adding something like this:

```
var acccess = new AccessProperty();
```

Comment: `(new AccessProperty()).myName` like this?

Comment: `access.myName`

Comment: @MinusFour, is there any other way besides that?

Comment: Sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. If you are not "storing" the value returned by `new AccessProperty()` somewhere, then you cannot access that value. Can you provide more information?

Comment: On a high level you seem to be asking whether `AccessProperty` can perform side effects and store the value in a different place. You could change the implementation of `AccessProperty` to `var obj = {}; function AccessProperty() { obj.myName = "Chris"; }; new AccessProperty(); console.log(obj.myName);` but I wouldn't advice doing that. It's hard to help without knowing the actually problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Felix Kling, that's the answer I wanted to read, so basically, the this keyword is not bound to anything...

Comment: Think about an equivalent `new Date()` without assigning that to anything. How do you access the "full year" if you can't call `dt.getFullYear()`. With `new AccessProperty();` you have created an object, but you don't have anything (a variable) that references that object.  The difference in your v. the "Date" example is using `this.myName = "Chris"` — then it all depends on what `this` refers to, which I think Mark Meyer explained well in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can access it directly like this:

```
acccess.myName
```

or use the square brackets:

```
acccess['myName']
```

**Without using the `new` operator**

If you call that function without the `new` operator, the property will be set in the `window` object of the page. This is not very recommended, but you could do:

```
AccessProperty();
console.log(window.myName);
```

Another possibility is to return a new object like this:

```
function AccessProperty() {
    return { myName: "Chris" };
}
var o = AccessProperty(); // not using 'new'
console.log(o.myName);
```

Comment: From the question: *"without adding something like this: `var acccess = new AccessProperty();`"*

Comment: FWIW, the first one only works in non-strict mode, in strict mode `this` will be `undefined`. I also don't think the OP has problems with using `new` but with assigning the return value to a variable. But tbh, the question doesn't make much sense to me `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Comment: @FelixKling I agree, the question is not very clear. I've explained some possibilities in order to provide some guidance. Thank you for the extra notes.

Comment: correct @FelixKling, without adding a reference to the new object and was thinking it defaulted to the window object but that is not correct either.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not clear what your ultimate goal is. `this` is a contextual reference that changes depending on the context of a function. When you use `new`, `this` refers to an object the js system creates for you and returns to the caller. Without `new` this will be the global window if you just call the function.

You can explicitly tell the function what `this` is with a function like `call()`:

```js
function AccessProperty() {
    this.myName = "Chris";
  }

let someObject = {}
AccessProperty.call(someObject)   // this will be someObject
console.log(someObject.myName)    // to which the function adds myName.
```

But that's seems like the hard way to do something, when you could just use `new` and get an object with a `myName` property.

As a demonstration of the dynamic nature of `this` consider the code:

```js
function AccessProperty() {
  this.myName = "Chris";
}

let o = {
  set: AccessProperty,
  talk() {console.log(this.myName)}
}
// because of the way it's called `this` in
// the function AccessProperty will be
// the object o 
o.set()   
o.talk()
console.log(o) // o now has a myName property
```

This behavior is very useful in some situations, if you don't want that behavior you are required to use `this` you can just define variables.

Comment: my ultimate goal is that the "this" keyword in this case is not bound to anything...

Comment: I don't really know what that means @Nora. `this` is a reference to some object, if it's not a reference to some object, then how can it have properties like `myName`? Are you sure you don't just want a variable: `let myName = "Chris"`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in strict mode you can do something like this

```
function AccessProperty(){
 this.name="ram"
}

function parent(){
  AccessProperty.bind(this)
  AccessProperty()
  console.log(this.name)
}


parent()
```

Here we have binded the scope of AccessProperty function to the scope of parent function. With this done the name will be in the scope of parent function

Comment: `this` inside `parent` will either be `undefined` in strict mode or `window` in non-strict mode. This only works accidentally because `this` is `window`. `AccessProperty` is not bound because you are not doing anything with the return value of `bind` (`bind` doesn't magically change `AccessProperty` itself). If you do `parent.call({})` instead (forcing `this` to be an object other than `window`) you will see that it does not work.

Comment: @FelixKling yes you are correct so what other options do we have

Comment: The question itself doesn't make much sense to me in its current state, I hope the OP will clarify.

Comment: The "this" keyword is not bound to anything. I was thinking it was bound to the window object by default or the object....

Comment: @Nora this keyword is bound to window object by default in this case for browsers

Comment: @Abhijet, you're wrong because the following code says so.... this == window // false when executing inside the new AccessProperty();

Comment: @Nora Thats totally fine. When you use new this will reference the new object.I hope you were willing not to use new

Comment: @Nora: If you are ultimate goal is to learn how `this` works, I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/0cc17c53ff772e20dfd6a7072c965df2486116e8/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes .